# How to create a live Ubuntu USB drive with persistence for BIOS using only terminal?

Tags: scripts, live-usb, persistence

I want to be able to boot from a live Ubuntu USB stick, and then using a rsync script permanently on that USB stick, make incremental snapshots *(backups)* of my main Debian system to a 2nd hard drive.

One would think that making a persistent live Ubuntu USB stick would be so easy, but most live USB makers don't allow for persistence, and those that do, haven't worked. This includes UNetBootin, even after I locally compiled and debugged the missing dependencies.  So I want a simple, terminal only, solution that I can understand and debug when necessary.

The simple dd from iso, and then add casper-rw file method had problems with partitioning tools getting confused by the non-standard efi partition image.  ([ref](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814745/in-ubuntu-iso-mbr-why-does-a-gpt-partition-overlap-the-boot-partition-and-make))

Some solutions, like UNetBootin got close to working, but when I tried to do a sudo -s to get a root shell, they would crash and dump, and destroy my live USB image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the solution (below) comes from [this](https://rudd-o.com/linux-and-free-software/a-better-way-to-create-a-customized-ubuntu-live-usb-drive) great article which comes close to working, but not quite, as it needs some updates a few places. But I suggest you look at it, as it's more complete in explanation of steps.

This is for my BIOS based laptop.  I'm guessing this might not work for a EUFI boot machine.

**TIPS:**

- Don't make the grub configuration file as that article above suggests, but rather as I show below.
- Once you finally have it working below, you'll find that over time the file system will become full unexpectedly.  I finally figured out that this occurs because Ubuntu is silently doing `apt-get update` and this will fill up all of your file space and then you'll get a warning message.  (It took me a couple of years to figure out what was going on.)

The initial fix was to do `apt-get clean` to dump the apt cache, but this doesn't really solve the underlying problem.  Then I tried simply disabling the wi-fi so it couldn't do an automatic update.  This works great for me!  Now my sticks last a long time without problems.

---

### Steps carefully tested to work:

**1. Download** Ubuntu 16.04 ISO image [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

**2. set** some variables to use below:

> ```
> iso=/path/to/isoimage #e.g. iso=~/Downloads/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso
>
> s=/mnt/isoimage   #Source mount point for ISO files (via loop file system)
> t=/media/USBRoot  #Target mount point for USB files in partition #1
> ```
>
> **!! Next, BE VERY CAREFUL to correctly point to the USB stick, and not to your hard drive, with this next step, as you can accidentally overwrite your hard disk.** (Tip: lookup and confirm using `lsblk` or the like)
>
> ```
> dev=/dev/sd?  #set the "?" to your USB drive letter, e.g. /dev/sdb
> ```

**3. Plugin and optionally erase** *If partitioning fails below the erase is recommended.  (Before when I had dd'ed an iso image to the usb device, I had to zero it out before I could make fdisk work properly again.).*

> ```
> sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=$dev  #bs=2048 is optional and doesn't seem to matter
> ```
>
> You'll get a message like this when it's done:
>
> ```
> dd: writing to ‘/dev/sdb’: No space left on device
> 30326785+0 records in
> 30326784+0 records out
> 15527313408 bytes (16 GB) copied, 4099.2 s, 3.8 MB/s
> ```
>
> *The erase step is because I've found that sometimes a quick format won't work.  I don't know for sure, but I suspect that 2nd copies of the partition map, or the like are being found and are confusing the partitioning software.  So writing all zeros to the USB stick before we begin seems to make sure that you're starting fresh.  But, and yes, I know, it takes LONG time to complete.*

**4. Make partitions.** Use a partitioning tool to put a msdos type partition map on the usb stick and partition it into two partitions as follows:

> **Partition 1)** VFAT32 partition for the kernel, ramdisk, grub, and persistence via casper-rw file.  Use all of the remaining space for this.
>
> **Partition 2)** bootable partition for the linux iso image.  Make it about 2G in size (because that's how big the .iso file is).
>
> The size of the #2 partition needs to be about 2g, so subtract this from the size of the drive and then divide by 512 to get the size of the #1 partition in sectors.  In my case that's 16gb - 2gb = 14gb / 512 = about 27343750 sectors.
>
> *Tip: unmount the device now if it is mounted or you will get an error when you are done with fdisk.  Don't use the graphical unmount button, as it seems to make the device un-findable (until the USB drive is unplugged and then replugged back in), rather use the terminal command as follows:*

? Question: I'm not sure why these partitions can't be swapped, with the boot partition as the first partition.  But for what it's worth, I tried that and could not get it to work.

> ```
> sudo umount ${dev}1
> sudo umount ${dev}2
> ```
>
> **Here's how:** You can use either fdisk, parted, gparted, or cfdisk but I like fdisk.
>
> ```
> sudo fdisk $dev
> o                             [create partition map], and then
>
> n (p) (1) (2048) 27343750     [new partition #1] 
> t c                           [change partition type to type c, or W95 FAT32], and
>
> n (p) (2) (default) (default) [new partition #2]
> t 2 83                        [type 83 or linux], then
> a (2)                         [set [toggle] the bootable flag], and
>
> p                             [check new table], and finally
> ```
>
> It should look something like this:
>
> ```
> Disk /dev/sdb: 14.5 GiB, 15527313408 bytes, 30326784 sectors
> Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> Disklabel type: dos
> Disk identifier: 0xa42995f9
>
> Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
> /dev/sdb1           2048 27343750 27341703   13G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
> /dev/sdb2  *    27344896 30326783  2981888  1.4G 83 Linux
> ```
>
> Then do this:
>
> ```
> w                         [write the partition table to the usb drive]
> ```
>
> You should get a response like this:
>
> ```
> The partition table has been altered.
> Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
> Syncing disks.
> ```
>
> or if you forgot to unmount it first then you will get this:
>
> ```
> The partition table has been altered.
> Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
> Re-reading the partition table failed.: Device or resource busy
>
> The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8).
> ```
>
> In which case you simply go back, unmount it as described above, and then run fdisk again and only hit **w**, and you're done.

**5. Write the iso image to the 2nd partition.**  *I struggled with whether to include a block size parameter or not here, (e.g. bs=2048), and in the end it appears it doesn't matter or has little effect.  Also note this partition doesn't need formatting, as the ISO will effectively format it when copied directly to the partition.*

> ```
> sudo dd if=$iso of=${dev}2
> ```

**6. Format** the first partition.  *Note, he formats this with VFAT32 (i.e. long file names version of FAT32).  I'm guessing this is to make it easy to read that partition on any machine (i.e. portability).  [I plan to see if ext3 might also work and will update this later w/ that test].*

> ```
> sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 -c ${dev}1   # for vFAT32 file system
> ```

**7. Mount partition #1** to be able to install files into it.

> ```
> sudo mkdir -p      $t
> sudo mount ${dev}1 $t
> ```

**8. Install grub** into the first sector of the usb stick and into the root directory in partition #1.

> ```
> sudo grub-install --no-floppy --root-directory=$t $dev
> ```

**9. Copy the kernel and ram disk files.**  (NOTE, this is revised from the article.  The kernel now comes as an *.efi version, (but it's still just a kernel), and initrd (the ram disk with all of the packages) is now compressed with lz rather than gz).  First we mount the image file (as a loop device) where we will get these two files from:

> ```
> sudo mkdir -p           $s
> sudo mount -o loop $iso $s
> sudo cp                 $s/casper/{vmlinuz.efi,initrd.lz} $t/boot/
> ```

**10. Create a file to hold the persistent file system.** Adjust the size if you want.  This is set as 1024x1mb=1gb.  Note that inside the casper-rw file it's an ext3 file system.  The name casper-rw is magic, so don't change it.

> ```
> sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=$t/casper-rw bs=1M count=1024  
> sudo mkfs.ext3 -F       $t/casper-rw     #takes a long time
> ```

**11. Create a simple grub configuration file.** Be sure to give it a (possibly newer?) cfg not conf file name extension so grub can find it ([ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/index.html#Top)).  Use your favorite editor, or use:

> ```
> sudo nano $t/boot/grub/grub.cfg
> ```

**12. Paste the following grub commands in.**

> *Notes: you can use echo and read here for more debugging if necessary. Also the "ro" "splash" and "quiet" are optional (but suggested) kernel options with mostly self explanatory behaviors.  See [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1599293) quite helpful post on how to use the GRUB> prompt if necessary.  I'm guessing that he had a *.conf file because this might have been for GRUB 1.0, rather than GRUB 2.0, and this might also explain the commands he had not working. Also note that the root is partition 1 (i.e. msdos1).*
>
> ```
> echo LOADING USB DRIVE
> echo 
> echo To continue press any key
> echo To abort press ^-alt-delete
> echo
> read
> echo Proceeding...
>
> set default=0
> set timeout=10
> set title="Ubuntu (Live)"
> set root=(hd0,msdos1)
>
> linux /boot/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper file=/preseed/ubuntu.seed persistent ro splash quiet
> echo vmlinuz.efi loaded
>
> initrd /boot/initrd.lz
> echo initrd.lz loaded
> echo
> echo Grub done. Booting...
> boot
> ```

**13. sync (recommended) and cleanup (optional):**

> ```
> sync
>
> sudo umount $s;  sudo rmdir  $s
> sudo umount $t;  sudo rmdir  $t
> ```

**14. Backup your new USB drive.**

> dd if=$dev of=/your/backup/location  #takes a long time
>
> To later restore it use the reverse:
>
> dd if=/your/backup/location of=$dev  #takes a long time

**15. Reboot** and hit a key to boot Ubuntu USB stick.

**16. Add your backup script** to it.  Here's my incremental script which deals with two laptops.  FIRST CHECK IT CAREFULLY FOR YOUR SYSTEM AND ADJUST IT AS NEEDED.  Name it **mybackup** and hard link **myrestore** to it (`ln mybackup myrestore`).  Set execution permissions with `chmod u+x my{backup,restore}`.  Run it with `./mybackup`

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> #Usage:
> #
> # mybackup                               - show list of current backups
> # myrestore                              - ''
> #
> # mybackup  <machine> <BackupFolderName> - machine: love2d or sharon-pc
> # myrestore <machine> <BackupFolderName> - by convention name is 'nn-descriptiveName' (so it sorts by date)
>
>
> #################################################################
> #################################################################
>
> ### PARTITIONS ######################
> #Partition labels (also used for mount point folder names):
> #  Note: use labels rather than UUID as they might be more controllable.
> BackupDrive='Linux backup'              # USB backup drive (I removed space from 'name' & it removed it from 'label')
>  BackupBase="$BackupDrive/Backups"      # Backup base folder directory & name
>      SubDir="files"
>
>
> ### PARTITIONS LABEL HELP:
> #lsblk -o +label        gives  (note older method was blkid, but this suggests we use lsblk):
> #NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT                              LABEL
> #sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
> #├─sda1   8:1    0   199M  0 part                                         SYSTEM
> #├─sda2   8:2    0 288.1G  0 part
> #├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part
> #├─sda4   8:4    0  29.3G  0 part                                         Shared
> #├─sda5   8:5    0  23.3G  0 part                                         d8root
> #├─sda6   8:6    0 119.5G  0 part                                         d8home
> #└─sda7   8:7    0   5.4G  0 part [SWAP]
>
> #sdc      8:32   0   3.7T  0 disk
> #├─sdc1   8:33   0   128M  0 part
> #├─sdc2   8:34   0   2.7T  0 part /media/ubuntu/Seagate Backup Plus Drive Seagate Backup Plus Drive
> #└─sdc3   8:35   0 976.6G  0 part                                         Linux backup
>
>
>
> ### MOUNTING 1of2 ######################
>  sudo umount "/mnt/$BackupDrive">& /dev/null    # --- cleanup from prior failed attempt:
>  sudo mkdir  "/mnt/$BackupDrive">& /dev/null; sudo mount -L "$BackupDrive"      "/mnt/$BackupDrive" -o defaults,suid >& /dev/null #Allow to set user owner of files
>
>
>
>
> ########################################################################
> ### FUNCTIONS #################################################################
>
> ####################
> function usage          { echo; echo "Usage: ${0##*/} [machine name: Love2d|Sharon-pc] [BackupFolderName]";echo;}
>
> ####################
>
> ####################
> #If parameter just show dirs for that machine, else show for both
> function myls {
>  echo -n "'$1' existing backups:"
>  if [ -d "$2" ]; then echo; ls -lFgG "$2" |grep -v ^total |grep ' [0-9][0-9]-' |sed 's/..................//'; else echo ' (none)'; fi;
> }
>
> ##################
> function currentbackups {
>  if [ "$1" ]; then
>         myls "$1"               "/mnt/$BackupBase/$1/$SubDir"
>  else
>         myls 'Love2d'           "/mnt/$BackupBase/Love2d/$SubDir"
>         echo
>         myls 'Sharon-pc'        "/mnt/$BackupBase/Sharon-pc/$SubDir"
>         echo
>  fi
> }
>
> ###################
> function badmachine     { echo "Machine type '$1' is invalid.";}
>
> ###################
> function cleanup        {
>  # echo "--- cleaning up --------------------------------------"
>  sudo umount "/mnt/$BackupDrive"
> }
>
> ########################################################################
> ########################################################################
>
>
> ### CHECK INPUTS #######################################################
> #Check if backup name paramter exists:
> if [ $# = 0 ]; then usage;                                                                                                              cleanup; exit;     fi
>
> if [ $# = 1 ]; then if [ "$1" != "Love2d" -a "$1" != "Sharon-pc" ]; then badmachine "$1"; usage; else usage; currentbackups "$1"; fi;                       cleanup; exit;     fi
>
> if [ $# = 2 ]; then if [ "$1" != "Love2d" -a "$1" != "Sharon-pc" ]; then badmachine "$1"; usage;                                         cleanup; exit; fi; fi
>
>
> ### MOUNTING 2of2 ######################
> if [ "$1" = 'Love2d' ]; then
>     MyHome='d8home'             # Love2 Debian /home      partition name
>     MyRoot='d8root'             # Love2 Debian /   (root) partition name
>   MyShared='Shared'             # Love2 Debian Shared     partition name
>
>  sudo umount "/mnt/$MyRoot"     >& /dev/null    # --- cleanup from prior failed attempt:
>  sudo umount "/mnt/$MyHome"     >& /dev/null    #
>  sudo umount "/mnt/$MyShared"   >& /dev/null    #
>
>  sudo mkdir  "/mnt/$MyRoot"     >& /dev/null; sudo mount -L "$MyRoot"           "/mnt/$MyRoot"                          >& /dev/null
>  sudo mkdir  "/mnt/$MyHome"     >& /dev/null; sudo mount -L "$MyHome"           "/mnt/$MyHome"                          >& /dev/null
>  sudo mkdir  "/mnt/$MyShared"   >& /dev/null; sudo mount -L "$MyShared"         "/mnt/$MyShared"                        >& /dev/null
>
> else
> #    MyHome='uhome'             # Love2 Ubuntu /home      partition name
> #    MyRoot='uroot'             # Love2 Ubuntu /   (root) partition name
>
>     MyHome='a41eaa3e-bd31-4ebc-86d4-cf8ed5f3e779'               # Love2 Ubuntu /home      partition name
>     MyRoot='f3b7424c-0144-42a6-8488-62fbee94d245'               # Love2 Ubuntu /   (root) partition name
>
>
>  sudo umount "/mnt/$MyRoot"     >& /dev/null    # --- cleanup from prior failed attempt:
>  sudo umount "/mnt/$MyHome"     >& /dev/null    #
>
> #sudo mkdir  "/mnt/$MyRoot"     >& /dev/null; sudo mount -L "$MyRoot"           "/mnt/$MyRoot"                          >& /dev/null
> #sudo mkdir  "/mnt/$MyHome"     >& /dev/null; sudo mount -L "$MyHome"           "/mnt/$MyHome"                          >& /dev/null
>
>  sudo mkdir  "/mnt/$MyRoot"     >& /dev/null; sudo mount -U "$MyRoot"           "/mnt/$MyRoot"                          >& /dev/null
>  sudo mkdir  "/mnt/$MyHome"     >& /dev/null; sudo mount -U "$MyHome"           "/mnt/$MyHome"                          >& /dev/null
> fi
>
>
> #=================================================================
> BackupDir="$BackupBase/$1/$SubDir/$2"   # /dir/BackupFolderName
>
>
> #rSync stuff:
> MyRsync="sudo rsync -aAXv --delete"
> RootExclude=" --exclude={\"/dev/*\",\"/lost+found\",\"/media/*\",\"/mnt/*\",\"/proc/*\",\"/run/*\",\"/sys/*\",\"/tmp/*\"}"
> HomeExclude=" --exclude='*cache*'"      #this does not work
>
> if [ "${0##*/}" = "mybackup" ]; then
> echo backing up...
>         sudo mkdir -p "/mnt/$BackupDir/root"    # Making directories to save backup to
>         sudo mkdir -p "/mnt/$BackupDir/home"
>
>         echo "--- Backing up:  / -----------------------------------"
>         $MyRsync $RootExclude   "/mnt/$MyRoot/"                 "/mnt/$BackupDir/root/"
>         echo "--- Backing up:  /home -------------------------------"
>
>         $MyRsync $HomeExclude   "/mnt/$MyHome/"                 "/mnt/$BackupDir/home/"
>
>    if [ "$MyShared" ]; then             #no shared partion on Sharon's machine
>         sudo mkdir -p "/mnt/$BackupDir/shared"
>         echo "--- Backing up:  Shared ------------------------------"
>         $MyRsync                "/mnt/$MyShared/"               "/mnt/$BackupDir/shared/"
>    fi
>
> else
>
>         # Confirm
>         read -p "YOU ARE ABOUT TO OVERWRITE YOUR PARTITIONS - CONFIRM (y/N)?" -n 1 -r; echo if [[ ! $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then echo "Aborting.";exit; fi
>         echo;
>         read -p "DANGER!  Really overwrite your hard disk partitions? (y/N)?" -n 1 -r; echo if [[ ! $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then echo "Aborting.";exit; fi
>
>         echo "--- Restoring:   / -----------------------------------"
>         $MyRsync                "/mnt/$BackupDir/root/"         "/mnt/$MyRoot"
>         echo "--- Restoring:   /home -------------------------------"
>         $MyRsync                "/mnt/$BackupDir/home/"         "/mnt/$MyHome"
>
>    if [ "$MyShared" ]; then             #no shared partion on Sharon's machine
>         echo "--- Restoring:   Shared ------------------------------"
>         $MyRsync                "/mnt/$BackupDir/shared/"       "/mnt/$MyShared"
>    fi
>
> fi
>
> cleanup
>  sudo umount "/mnt/$MyRoot"     ;sudo rmdir "/mnt/$MyRoot"
>  sudo umount "/mnt/$MyHome"     ;sudo rmdir "/mnt/$MyHome"
>
> if [ "$MyShared" ]; then                #no shared partion on Sharon's machine
>  sudo umount "/mnt/$MyShared"   ;sudo rmdir "/mnt/$MyShared"
> fi
>
>  echo "=== DONE. ============================================"
>
> exit 0
> ```

Comment: Feedback to help others: Stage 9: 'mount: /mnt/isoimage: WARNING: device write-protected, mounted read-only.' Maybe doesn't matter. However, then I get this error 'cp: cannot stat...' because the file 'vmlinuz.efi' doesn't exist in '$s/casper/' but one called 'vmlinuz' does so I changed the command to copy that instead. For me, making a Linux Mint 19.3 at least. I'll feedback on whether this works.  Ah, doesn't work; the grub menu crashes out to grub prompt.

Comment: @Little me, Haven't tested this with Mint, only Ubuntu.  Ubuntu has an interesting and different file system boot structure.  What part of step 9 failed for you, i.e. line 9.1, 9.2 9.3?  I think that the mount is read only; in 9.3 the cp should work to copy the 2 files from casper to boot.  (It's been a few years since I did this, so it might take me a  little bit to refresh my mind about this.)

Answer (score 0):

I think we are doing the same things. Let us exchange ideas and help each other :-)

Maybe the only difference is that I started earlier. Have a look at my new tool ***dus***, that I hope will soon be renamed to 'mkusb version 12'.

***dus*** works with *zenity menus* when there is a graphical desktop environment and zenity is available, otherwise works with *dialog menus* when dialog is available, otherwise uses a *plain text* user interface, which is what you asked for (and made, because there was no early reply).

***dus*** consists of a set of bash shell-scripts, and you are welcome to read them and understand how they work. The scripts are available via ppa:mkusb/unstable or phillw.net. See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui#dus_-_a_revamped_interface_of_mkusb_and_mkusb-nox) and [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&page=22&p=13570139#post13570139) for more details.

The following text dump is the ***plain text dialogue*** (input to and output from the terminal), when making a persistent live drive. I used a slow USB 2 pendrive, the write speed is only 6 MB/s. It can be 4-5 times higher with a good USB 3 pendrive in a USB 2 port and still higher in a USB 3 port.

```
$ ssh sudodus@my_server
sudodus@my_server's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-45-generic i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

0 paket kan uppdateras.
0 uppdateringar är säkerhetsuppdateringar.

*** /dev/sda8 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***

sudodus@xenial32 ~ $ cd /media/multimed-2/test/mkmkusb/dus
sudodus@xenial32 /media/multimed-2/test/mkmkusb/dus $ dus lubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso 
 dus 0.0.0 
[sudo] password for sudodus: 
dus wants the program(s) 
mkusb-common 'to make a persistent live drive and to get a good GUI experience'
usb-pack-efi 'only to make a persistent live drive'
 Please install the corresponding package(s) 
Press Enter to continue, or wait 8 seconds 

 dus 0.0.0 - Cloning, live linux, windows / Persistent live
 ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────


             ┌──────Move between items with the arrow keys────────┐
             │                 - Do USB Stuff -                   │
             │       Welcome and Notice about Overwriting         │
             │ The target device will be completely overwritten   │
             │ ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ │
             │ │c  Cloning iso file, [compressed] image file or │ │
             │ │l  'Live-only' or linux installer from iso file │ │
             │ │p  'Persistent live' - only Debian and Ubuntu   │ │
             │ │w  extracting Windows installer                 │ │
             │ │q  Quit                                         │ │
             │ └────────────────────────────────────────────────┘ │
             │                                                    │
             │                                                    │
             │                                                    │
             │                                                    │
             ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
             │             <  OK  >       <Avbryt>                │
             └────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

## oops - I have dialog installed - so I had better use the option -t ##
##        to make a demo with the plain text interface                ##

clean if necessary and return
sudodus@xenial32 /media/multimed-2/test/mkmkusb/dus $ dus -t lubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso 
 dus 0.0.0 
dus wants the program(s) 
mkusb-common 'to make a persistent live drive and to get a good GUI experience'
usb-pack-efi 'only to make a persistent live drive'
 Please install the corresponding package(s) 
Press Enter to continue, or wait 8 seconds 
+------------------------  Do USB Stuff  -------------------------+
|              Welcome and Notice about Overwriting               |
|        The target device will be completely overwritten         |
+------------------------  quit with (q)  ------------------------+
Cloning,live-only,windows / Persistent-live / Quit (c/l/p/w/q) p
Drive that contains source file: /dev/sdc
Live drive, that is booted from: /dev/sda
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Available drives (mass storage devices)
Dev  Target name/model              Size   Bus  Kind of device    
sdd  SanDisk_Cruzer                  15G   usb  USB or memory card
Example: add 'sdx':  /dev/sdx
Select target device /dev/sdd
p_target: target=/dev/sdd
Select 'MSDOS' partition table - default GPT?               (y/N) 
Select 'usb-pack-efi' - default grub from iso file?         (y/N) 
Select 'download and install' security update - default NO? (y/N) 
Enter 'percentage' for persistence - default 50  (enter: 1 - 100) 75
settings=
percent=75
Prepare  persistent live  system from
'lubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso'
to the target device (drive) '/dev/sdd'
MODEL            NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL                      SIZE
Cruzer           sdd                                        15G
                 ├─sdd1 ntfs    usbdata                    3,5G
                 ├─sdd2                                      1M
                 ├─sdd3 vfat    lub1604164                 122M
                 ├─sdd4 iso9660 Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS amd64  874M
                 └─sdd5 ext4    casper-rw                 10,5G
 Final checkpoint, go ahead? (g/N) g
lubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
/dev/sdd
75
settings=
-----
live system or temporary superuser permissions
lubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
/dev/sdd
75
settings=
source=lubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
target=/dev/sdd
percent=75
msdos=false
upefi=false
dni=false
source=lubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
ls -l  lubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
lrwxrwxrwx 1 olle olle 67 okt 22 21:44 lubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso -> /media/multimed-2/CD/ubuntu/16.04/lubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
start [dus-persistent 0.0.0] @ 2016-11-17 19:15:23
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Making a USB boot drive or memory card ..........................
ubuntu
grub_n_iso "$source" "$target" "$result"
grub_n_iso lubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso /dev/sdd 
***** tu=/dev/sdd ****************************************************
selected target partition table: 'gpt'
mount: /dev/loop0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
 Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS "Xenial Xerus" - Release amd64 
mount: /dev/loop0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
select_boot_system: usb-pack_efi is available
select_boot_system: usb-pack_efi: using variable 'upefi=false'
'lubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso' is identified as the source ISO file
<pre>
MODEL            NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL                     MOUNTPOINT  SIZE
Cruzer           sdd                                                   15G
                 |-sdd1 ntfs    usbdata                               3,5G
                 |-sdd2                                                 1M
                 |-sdd3 vfat    lub1604164                            122M
                 |-sdd4 iso9660 Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS amd64             874M
                 `-sdd5 ext4    casper-rw                            10,5G
</pre>
Using the file '/usr/share/mkusb/grub.cfg'
Clean for a GUID partition table
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): This option deletes all partitions and creates a new protective MBR.
Proceed? (Y/N): 
Command (? for help): 
Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/sdd.
The operation has completed successfully.
Wipe the first megabyte (mibibyte) to get a clean boot area
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1,0 MB, 1,0 MiB) copied, 0,00227566 s, 461 MB/s
Wait 5 seconds and a little more ...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Selected percentage of remaining space for persistence = 75 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

preparing /dev/sdd3  ------------------------------------------------
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1,0 MB, 1,0 MiB) copied, 0,290228 s, 3,6 MB/s
umount: /dev/sdd3: not mounted
mkfs.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
/dev/sdd3 has 64 heads and 32 sectors per track,
hidden sectors 0x1000;
logical sector size is 512,
using 0xf8 media descriptor, with 249856 sectors;
drive number 0x80;
filesystem has 2 32-bit FATs and 1 sector per cluster.
FAT size is 1922 sectors, and provides 245980 clusters.
There are 32 reserved sectors.
Volume ID is 3cfbdfa9, no volume label.

preparing /dev/sdd1  ------------------------------------------------
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1,0 MB, 1,0 MiB) copied, 0,317438 s, 3,3 MB/s
umount: /dev/sdd1: not mounted
Cluster size has been automatically set to 4096 bytes.
Creating NTFS volume structures.
Creating root directory (mft record 5)
Creating $MFT (mft record 0)
Creating $MFTMirr (mft record 1)
Creating $LogFile (mft record 2)
Creating $AttrDef (mft record 4)
Creating $Bitmap (mft record 6)
Creating $Boot (mft record 7)
Creating backup boot sector.
Creating $Volume (mft record 3)
Creating $BadClus (mft record 8)
Creating $Secure (mft record 9)
Creating $UpCase (mft record 0xa)
Creating $Extend (mft record 11)
Creating system file (mft record 0xc)
Creating system file (mft record 0xd)
Creating system file (mft record 0xe)
Creating system file (mft record 0xf)
Creating $Quota (mft record 24)
Creating $ObjId (mft record 25)
Creating $Reparse (mft record 26)
Syncing root directory index record.
Syncing $Bitmap.
Syncing $MFT.
Updating $MFTMirr.
Syncing device.
mkntfs completed successfully. Have a nice day.
preparing /dev/sdd5  ------------------------------------------------
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1,0 MB, 1,0 MiB) copied, 1,7128 s, 612 kB/s
umount: /dev/sdd5: not mounted
mke2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Creating filesystem with 2743296 4k blocks and 686784 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 3c0ee31f-b5f2-4b21-8ac8-bb8941c39697
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done 

mount: /media/multimed-2/CD/ubuntu/16.04/lubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso is already mounted
fatlabel: warning - lowercase labels might not work properly with DOS or Windows
tune2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
source=lubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
item 60
umount: /dev/sdd3: not mounted
mount /dev/sdd3 /tmp/dus.KMlnQuCB3J
/dev/sdd3       121M   512  121M   1% /tmp/dus.KMlnQuCB3J
item 65
umount: /dev/sdd1: not mounted
/dev/sdd1       3,5G   19M  3,5G   1% /tmp/dus.FkiHYIJh2I
 BIOS Bootloader:  Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
 64-bit bootloader: copy the boot files from the iso file 
looper=/tmp/dus.zAxhAauNxN
targ1=/tmp/dus.KMlnQuCB3J
rsync: symlink "/tmp/dus.KMlnQuCB3J/ubuntu" -> "." failed: Operation not permitted (1)
rsync: symlink "/tmp/dus.KMlnQuCB3J/dists/stable" -> "xenial" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
rsync: symlink "/tmp/dus.KMlnQuCB3J/dists/unstable" -> "xenial" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.1]
rsync:  don't worry,  symlink errors are *expected*
because of the target file system.
Using the file '/tmp/dus.KMlnQuCB3J/boot/grub/grub.cfg'
 set security upgrade action to 'Display immediately' 
umount: /dev/sdd4: not mounted
 Please wait while copying and syncing until 'Done' is written ... 
< "lubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso" pv | dd of=/dev/sdd4 bs=4096
 855MiB 0:02:15 [6,33MiB/s] [================================>] 100%            
218880+0 records in
218880+0 records out
896532480 bytes (897 MB, 855 MiB) copied, 148,466 s, 6,0 MB/s
Syncing the target device ...
Wait 5 seconds and a little more ...
<pre>
parted -s "/dev/sdd" print
Model: SanDisk Cruzer (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 16,0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 2      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB               primary  bios_grub
 3      2097kB  130MB   128MB   fat32        primary  boot, esp
 4      130MB   1046MB  916MB                primary
 5      1046MB  12,3GB  11,2GB  ext2         primary
 1      12,3GB  16,0GB  3746MB  ntfs         primary  msftdata

lsblk -o MODEL,NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE "/dev/sdd"
MODEL            NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL                     MOUNTPOINT  SIZE
Cruzer           sdd                                                   15G
                 |-sdd1 ntfs    usbdata                               3,5G
                 |-sdd2                                                 1M
                 |-sdd3 vfat    lub1604164                            122M
                 |-sdd4 iso9660 Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS amd64             874M
                 `-sdd5 ext4    casper-rw                            10,5G
</pre>
 Done :-) 
The target device is ready to use.
'lubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso'
was installed
Cleanup after dus-persistent finished :-)
Cleanup after dus-persistent finished :-)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time used [by dus-persistent] = 276 s; 00:04:36


Check the result (scroll if possible), press Enter to finish 
p_clean:
live system or temporary superuser permissions
Cloning,live-only,windows / Persistent-live / Quit (c/l/p/w/q) q
clean if necessary and return
sudodus@xenial32 /media/multimed-2/test/mkmkusb/dus $
```

Comment: "I think we are doing the same things. Let us exchange ideas and help each other"  Thanks,  but I've got my solution working.  Just posted it here for others to be able to use as a guide.  Good luck to you.  I spent quite a bit of time getting this to work, and I imagine that you have struggled with it too.

Comment: Yes, I have spent a lot of time with my version, and with helping people at the Ubuntu Forums. Good luck to you too :-)